# Redefine array, search through and return $var

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 70170b60a4
        [name] => vip
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 355a5f8cbd
        [name] => TEST LIST2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => d1c2deef1d
        [name] => test list
    )

)
```

I call it $listInfo.

Now I want to take the info from this array and create a new one, that looks like this:

```
  Array
( 
 [70170b60a4] => vip
 [355a5f8cbd] => TEST LIST2
 [d1c2deef1d] => test list
)
```

I do this by:

```
foreach ($listinfo as $key) {
$list = array($key['id'] => $key['name'] );
}
```

Then I want to return the value (id) of vip:

```
$listId = array_search('vip', $list);
```

My problem is that the foreach loop does only create an array with the last values in the first array. so I get:

```
Array
(
     [d1c2deef1d] => test list
)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I want all the values from the first array in there. Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `foreach` loop, you're creating a new array every time.

Try this:

```
$list = array();

foreach ($listinfo as $key) {
    $list[$key['id']] = $key['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are redefining `$list` every loop iteration. what you want to do is:

```
$list = array();
foreach($listinfo as $a) {
   $list[$a['id']] = $a['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new array each time your loop is executed, try this:

```
$list = array();//make the array, once and only once
foreach ($listinfo as $key)
{
    $list[$key['id']] = $key['name'];//assign new key, new value to EXISTING array
}
```